# Appium insallation on CentOS

Tags: centos, appium

I need to install Appium for CentOS version 6. I already have appium environment in my windows system. I searched on internet but found nothing specific for CentOS. Can anyone provide detail documentation or steps? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you are talking about the desktop version, its only available for windows and mac, but you can install appium on linux using command line, check this page http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#running-appium-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up android automation in linux:

a) linuxbrew installation: https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew
b) Download and extract android sdk to home folder: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
c) Set android sdk path:
   1. Open file by command:

> sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

2. Add these lines at the end of the file:

#### adding linux brew path

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

#android
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/asci/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

3. Close the file.
4. Run the command:

   > source ~/.bashrc

e) Run these commands one by one:

```
1.
```

> android

(It will open the sdk manager, and install all the sdk tools from the Tools folder and Android 6.0 API 23)

```
2.
```

> brew install node

```
3.
```

> npm install -g appium

```
4.
```

> appium &

(It will start the appium server needed to run automation)